# Skipping the first step in a loop for the first iteration

Tags: c#, for-loop, goto

I am learning C# using the C# programming yellow book by Rob Miles. In this he is discussing an example of a calculator for determining the total glass area needed in square meters. I recreated this code and wanted to try to improve on it with things that made sense for me. For example in his code he used a lot of blank lines which didn't look appealing to me. I wanted to try making it look a bit more clean. I mainly want to eliminate this first blank line, but make sure the blank line would appear on the next one.

This is the original code.

```
double width, height, woodLength, glassArea;

        const double MAX_WIDTH = 5.0;
        const double MIN_WIDTH = 0.5;
        const double MAX_HEIGHT = 3.0;
        const double MIN_HEIGHT = 0.75;

        string widthString, heightString;

        do {
            Console.Write("\nGive the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            width = double.Parse(widthString);

            if (width < MIN_WIDTH){
                Console.WriteLine("Width is too small.");
            }

            if (width > MAX_WIDTH){
                Console.WriteLine("Width is too large.");
            }
        } while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```

I tried to use a goto, but because the loop is a different method(?) it didn't work. Through some googling I found out that goto is very bad practice, but I can't think of any other methods to use.
(nor do i know any)

```
            Console.Write("Give the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");

        goto first_loop;

        do {
            Console.Write("\nGive the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");
            first_loop:
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            width = double.Parse(widthString);

            if (width < MIN_WIDTH){
                Console.WriteLine("Width is too small.");
            }

            if (width > MAX_WIDTH){
                Console.WriteLine("Width is too large.");
            }
        } while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```

Comment: I don't see a blank line in the original

Comment: @Stefan, it's the `\n` at the beginning of the prompt.

Comment: I mean the \n in the loop. I want the first time it appears it  to not be there, but when it loops because of an incorrect number there should be a \n so it is separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mainly want to eliminate this first blank line, but make sure the
> blank line would appear on the next one.

Remove the `\n` from the prompt, and instead add it to the end of both of the error messages:

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Give the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");
    widthString = Console.ReadLine();
    width = double.Parse(widthString);

    if (width < MIN_WIDTH)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Width is too small.\n");
    }
    else if (width > MAX_WIDTH)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Width is too large.\n");
    }
} while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```

If I were writing this myself, though, I'd use a boolean to indicate the overall success and check that in the while loop conditional.  I'd also use `double.TryParse()` as shown below:

```
bool valid = false;
do
{
    valid = true; // assume good until proven otherwise
    Console.Write("Give the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");
    widthString = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(widthString, out width))
    {
        if (width < MIN_WIDTH || width >MAX_WIDTH )
        {
            valid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Width is too " + ((width<MIN_WIDTH) ? "small" : "large") + ".");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid width entry. Please try again.");
        valid = false;
    }
    
    if (!valid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: ... Another option is just to put an `WriteLine` at the end I guess. Although I am not wearing my glasses, I tend to over look things today.

Comment: Right...just depends on whether they do NOT want an extra line if the value WAS within range.  That was not addressed in the description.

Comment: Or use a `bool` to indicate you're in the first iteration, setting it to false in the loop. Several ways to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for this, the first solution seems obvious now that you said it. I also looked at your method and tried figuring out how it works. I was wondering if you could clarify a few things for me and if I got it right

- is it necessary here to assign valid as false right at the very beginning or is just good practice?

- If i understood it correctly the double.TryParse tries to parse the string into a double, it returns a true or false value here. and if true you use out to put the results in width?.

- ((width < MIN_WIDTH) ? "small" : "large") what does the ? and : mean in this context?

Comment: The [default for bool is false](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values), so it is not required to set it. `TryParse` returns true/false based on the parse, and puts the numeric value into the `out` parameter. Now when the user types in something that is completely not numeric, you can display a nice message instead of your program crashing.  The `?` here is the [conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and is simply short hand for an `if...else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you also do not want additional blank lines at the end as in the solution by @Idle_Mind, you could do something like this

```
bool isFirstRun = true;
do
{
    if (!isFirstRun) Console.WriteLine();
    isFirstRun = false;

    Console.Write("Give the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + ": ");
    widthString = Console.ReadLine();
    width = double.Parse(widthString);

    if (width < MIN_WIDTH)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Width is too small.");
    }

    if (width > MAX_WIDTH)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Width is too large.");
    }
} while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```